# Curl - same actions, different results?

Tags: php, curl

I'd be much appreciative if someone could explain to me how curl is getting two different results from what I feel should be similar commands.

I have a php script which returns a daily extract upon accessing a semi-public (open but not indexed) URL. We've started collecting more sensitive information and need it secured.

I've been successfully collecting the information via Curl thusly:

```
curl -o C:\localdirectory\extract.csv http://foo.bar/daily_data_extract.php
```

I have access to the site assets of course, via SFTP and I figured the commmand would work like this:

```
curl -o C:\localdirectory\extract.csv sftp://user:pass@foo.bar/blah/htdocs/daily_data_extract.php -k
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I'm just getting the PHP code downloaded as a CSV and not the results I need. I'm new to Curl and previously just used wget (which doesn't support SFTP to my understanding).

I'd appreciate the pointers on what I'm missing!

Comment: `sftp` accesses the file contents directly. PHP is an interpreted language, and the php interpreter runs in your web server, which handles the http requests. You should look into ssl, which encrypts traffic from the webserver to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP must be executed by the web server, for example Apache. When you visit a PHP file via HTTP, you are seeing the *result* of that script being executed. If you retrieve the file directly, you are getting the raw script instead.

If you need to access the result of the script securely, your web server could be set up with HTTPS... however, this only protects against eavesdropping, and the URL would still be publicly accessible. Alternatively, you could modify the script and have it direct output to a file, which you can then download via SFTP.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, in the first instance, curl, by accessing via HTTP is invoking the server-side execution of the PHP script, but by accessing via SFTP, it is not invoking that execution.